# MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The tick1On function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, deprecation-warning

How to update depreciated `tick1On` and `tick2On` in **matplotlib**?

```
    # Turn off all the ticks
    for t in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
        t.tick1On = False
        t.tick2On = False
    for t in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
        t.tick1On = False
        t.tick2On = False
```

**Warnings**

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:151: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The tick1On function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use Tick.tick1line.set_visible instead.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:152: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The tick2On function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use Tick.tick2line.set_visible instead.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:154: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The tick1On function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use Tick.tick1line.set_visible instead.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:155: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The tick2On function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use Tick.tick2line.set_visible instead.
```

Updating the code as per warnings throwing an error

```
    # Turn off all the ticks
    for t in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
        t.Tick.tick1line.set_visible = False
        t.Tick.tick2line.set_visible = False
    for t in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
        t.Tick.tick1line.set_visible = False
        t.Tick.tick2line.set_visible = False
```

```
<ipython-input-5-674bddf7d454> in pretty_plot_confusion_matrix(df_cm, annot, cmap, fmt, fz, lw, cbar, figsize, show_null_values, pred_val_axis)
    149     # Turn off all the ticks
    150     for t in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
--> 151         t.Tick.tick1line.set_visible = False
    152         t.Tick.tick2line.set_visible = False
    153     for t in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():

AttributeError: 'XTick' object has no attribute 'Tick'
```

I'm able to hide these depreciation warnings using

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)
```

But I want to update it with latest compatibility. The complete code can be found here [confusion_matrix_pretty_print.py](https://github.com/wcipriano/pretty-print-confusion-matrix/blob/master/confusion_matrix_pretty_print.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error message meant for you to substitute like so:

```py
for t in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    t.tick1line.set_visible(False)
    t.tick2line.set_visible(False)
```